# Service Stack is double escaping quotes in my data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, servicestack

I've got a DTO object that has a JsonObject (Data) property on it so that I can store the serialized objects.

I've included the service stack service below.

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BuffaloInspection.WebApi.Services
{
    [Route("/_layouts/api/test")]
    public class ItemDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public JsonObject Data { get; set; }
        public string DataStr { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestService : Service
    {
        public ItemDTO POST(ItemDTO request)
        {
            var response = new ItemDTO();

            response.ID = request.ID;
            response.Title = request.Title;

            //Failing
            response.DataStr = request.Data.ToJson();
            response.Data = JsonObject.Parse(response.DataStr);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the following html page to make a call to the above mentioned service.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="SSTest">
<head>
    <title>Service Stack Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div>ID:<input type="text" name="id" ng-model="item.ID" value="1" /></div>
        <div>Title:<input type="text" name="title" ng-model="item.Title" value="Test" /></div>
        <div>Length:<input type="text" name="length" ng-model="item.Data.Length" value="10" /></div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" value="save" ng-click="save(item)">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        var app = angular.module('SSTest', []);

        app.controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);
        function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
            $scope.item = {
                ID: 1,
                Title: 'Test "',
                Data: {
                    Length: '10 "'
                }
            };

            $scope.save = function (data) {
                console.log('before:');
                console.log(data);
                $http.post("http://localhost:8001/_layouts/api/test/", data).then(function (result) {
                    console.log('after: ');
                    console.log(result.data);
                    $scope.item = result.data;
                });
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I load up the page and hit save. At this point the client side object like so:
`{"ID":1,"Title":"Test \"","Data":{"Length":"10 \""}}`

When the code reaches the server code line commented with `//Failing` above the problem is that the `request.Data` object contains an already escaped field, The `ToJson()` call escapes that again so that when I retrieve the data I get `10\\\"`.

request.Data is a JSON object with this info: `[0] {[Length, 10 \"]}`
response.DataStr now contains `{"Length":"10 \\\""}`

Back on the client side my return object is now has extra escapes

Does anyone know how to make sure that special characters are not double escaped?

Comment: If `request.Data` already contains escaped JSON why are you even calling `ToJson`?

Comment: Because ToJson gives me the string representation I need to store in the database.

Answer (score 2):

We have exactly the same situation, we use a nested JsonObject in order to have a dynamic object (although restricted with Json-Schema).

Everything (serialization / deserialization) works nicely until we use OrmLite. When the TypeSerializer deserializes the stored dto, it adds quotes to string values in the nested JsonObject, so when the Dto is deserialized to the wire it gets the extra \".

To deal with this we, like you, have another dto for store purposes, but using instead:

```
toStore.DataStr = request.Data.SerializeToString();
response.Data = JsonObject.Parse(toStore.DataStr);
```

This is working for us with Service Stack 3.9.66

Answer (score 1):

The ServiceStack.Text project has no known problems with Serializing and Deserializing with escaped characters. See the following passing unit tests at

[ServiceStack.Text / tests / ServiceStack.Text.Tests / JsonTests / EscapedCharsTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/JsonTests/EscapedCharsTests.cs?source=cc#L29)

More specificly if I run the following code I get the expected output. Looks like something you are doing along the way is confusing the Serializer.

```
var o = new JsonObject();
o.Add("Length", "10\"");
Debug.WriteLine(o.ToJson());
// Outputs   {"Length":"10\""}
```

**Updated: Estyn comment helped me think about this again.** 
Take a look at this extension method [string Get(this Dictionary map, string key)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/15dfd142863b9dacd6c1880eae7a83be259b6bca/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonObject.cs#L20).

This test will now pass:

```
var o1 = new JsonObject {{"Length", "10\""}};
var json = o1.ToJson();

var o2 = json.FromJson<JsonObject>();
Assert.AreEqual(o2.Get("Length"), "10\"");
```

If you use the Get extension method it will unescape the extra escaping. You can step through the Serializers and you go down pretty deep into the code. Hard for me to say if its a bug or not due to the odd nature of having serializing embedded JSON.

Comment: The simple test you mentioned does indeed work. However, if you have a object inside your main object incoming from a client post request the serialization stops working.
I've updated my question to clarify how I am using service stack. Is there anything in there that you can see would confuse the serializer?

Comment: Just tried out some test based on the EscapedCharsTests, this test fails, but if you remove the escaped quote then it passes. I believe this illustrates the problem mark is having, although I don't know if this is the expected behavior

    [Test]
    public void Can_deserialize_text_with_escaped_chars2()
    {
        var o = new JsonObject();
        o.Add("Length", "10\"");
        var text = o.ToJson();
        var parsed = JsonObject.Parse(text);
        var result = parsed.ToJson();
        Assert.AreEqual(text, result);
    }